# Getting the limit of a Riemann sum expressed as a definite integral and not the value of the integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I know that the limit of a Riemann sum is a definite integral. For example:

$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sin{(5+3\frac{k}{n})}\frac{3}{n}=\int_3^8\sin{x}\,\text{d}x$

However, when I ask Mathematica to evaluate the `Limit` expression, it evaluates the integral (it gives me $\cos{5} - \cos{8}$). Is there a way to obtain the symbolic definite integral as the result?

I tried to change 
$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sin{(5+3\frac{k}{n})}\frac{3}{n}$ to $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sin{(a+b\frac{k}{n})}\frac{b}{n}$ and I still get $\cos{a} - \cos{a + b}.$

Comment: Please edit your post to include the code that you entered in *Mathematica*, properly formatted in code blocks. Click the grey question mark on the right side of the editing toolbar for formatting help. Welcome to *Mathematica*.stackexchange!

Comment: The question is rather unclear for me. *Mathematica* is capable of summing trigonometric series, so it will of course quickly sum the one you have.

Comment: The simple answer is: no. Mathematica can confirm that the Riemann sum is the same as the definite integral, but it can not deliver the evaluation you ask for.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP is asking for functionality that is not supported given the constraints the OP is putting on the solution.

Answer (score 2):

$\lim_{n\to \infty } \, \left(\sum _{k=1}^n \frac{3 \sin \left(\frac{3 k}{n}+5\right)}{n}\right)=\int_a^b \sin (x) \, dx$

```
Limit[Sum[Sin[5 + 3*(k/n)]*(3/n), {k, 1, n}], n -> Infinity] == Integrate[Sin[x], {x, a, b}]

N[FindInstance[Limit[Sum[Sin[5 + 3*(k/n)]*(3/n), {k, 1, n}], n -> Infinity] == Integrate[Sin[x], {x, a, b}], {a, b}]]
```

> $\{\{a\to 3.3\, +1.6 i,b\to -292.035+1.76303 i\}\}$

Answer (score 2):

Calculate your Limit with variables instead of numbers:

```
      lim[x_] = Limit[Sum[Sin[a + x*(k/n)]*(x/n), {k, 1, n}], n -> Infinity]
     (*  Cos[a] - Cos[a + x]  *)
```

Get the integrand of the integral by diffentiating:

```
   integrand[x_] =  D[lim[x], x]

              (*  Sin[a + x]  *)
```

Test it with a slight change of integration limit:

```
        Integrate[integrand[y], {y, 0, x}]

         (* Cos[a] - Cos[a + x] *)
```