# Taking the limit of a sum

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, summation

Question: Why can't Mathematica calculate this limit in this way? And what can I do to fix it?

```
Limit[Sum[2/n (1 + (2 i - 1)/n)^(1/3), {i, 1, n}], n -> \[Infinity]] //N
```

Of course this limit is a Riemann-Sum, so it can also be represented by:

```
Integrate[(1 + x)^(1/3), {x, 0, 2}] // N
```

Finally, I noticed from [another question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/135940/30033) that this does work:

```
Limit[Sum[Sin[a + x*(k/n)]*(x/n), {k, 1, n}], n -> Infinity]
```

But what is the essential difference with my code?

Comment: `Sum` and `Limit` are evaluated separately. In the first case `Sum` cannot be evaluated for arbitrary `n`. In the second, it can.

Comment: You can try ``Needs["NumericalCalculus`"]; NLimit[Sum[..], n -> \[Infinity]]`` -- it gives exactly the same answer as `Integrate[..] // N`.

Comment: Try `Limit[Sum[2/n CubeRoot[1 + (2 i - 1)/n], {i, 1, n}], n -> \[Infinity]]`

Comment: @LouisB Why does CubeRoot work?!

Comment: I do not know why `CubeRoot` works and `Power[... , 1/3]` does not.  I try to use the `Surd` function for roots.  See this [question about n-th roots](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21151)  and this [question about real roots](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3886) for more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for Mathematica to be able to compute the limit of a sum, it (usually) needs to be able to first compute the sum itself.  In this case, this is failing to do so when using `Power` but not when using the `Surd`.  The reason is that, in general, you can't split the fraction inside the root to combine the $\frac{1}{n}$ in the first term with the $\frac{1}{n^{1/3}}$ in the second term. Under the assumptions of what $n$ is in your sum, however, this is valid, and if you simplify the expression using appropriate assumptions, then both `Sum` and `Limit` will succeed:

```
Simplify[2/n (1 + (2 i - 1)/n)^(1/3), n>0]
(* (2 (-1 + 2 i + n)^(1/3))/n^(4/3) *)

Limit[Sum[%, {i, 1, n}], n -> Infinity]    
(* 3/4 (-1 + 3 3^(1/3)) *)
```

(Note that in fact we know that $n\geq1$ or the sum is empty, but it is sufficient that $n$ is positive in the simplification step).  It is a small bug that `Sum` doesn't recognize this automatically, and I have filed it for the developer to fix.

As for why `Surd` and `CubeRoot` work in this case.  Since they are by definition functions from reals to reals (and in particular, do not use the principle root), it is in fact the case that $  \frac{\sqrt[3]{f(n)}}{n} = \sqrt[3]{\frac{f(n)}{n^3}}$.  So `Sum` doesn't have to check any validity conditions and succeeds.